Characterize the operators $G$ for which $\mathcal{F}_{G}$ is geometric.
We call an $\Bbb R$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ geometrical if $$\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{F})=\bigcap_{x \in |\mathcal{F}|} \ker x = 0.$$ Here $|\mathcal{F}|$ is the set of all $\Bbb R$-algebra homomorphisms of $\mathcal{F}$ onto $\Bbb R$.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $G: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator. Consider the algebra $\mathcal{F}_{G}$ generated by $G^{k}, k=$ $0,1, \ldots$, as a vector space. Characterize the operators $G$ for which $\mathcal{F}_{G}$ is geometric.

I have a a feeling that the solution here relates to the diagonalizability of $G$ and its nilpotency, but I have not managed to come up with a proper argument. Any ideas what could be done here?

What is your definition of $\mathbb{R}$-algebra ? is it associative unital ?

Yes, associative and unital. @GreginGre

I just give the rough ideas., since you want ideas but not a full solution.
I have not checked the details, so I hope I am correct. Apologies if not.
By definition, your ideal is the intersection of maximal ideals of $\mathcal{F}$ whose residue field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $\mu$ be the minimal polynomial of $G$ over $\mathbb{R}$.
Then $\mathcal{F}_G\simeq \mathbb{R}[X]/(\mu)$, so they have isomorphic correponding ideals .
I wil ldenote by $\mathcal{I}$ the ideal we get for $\mathbb{R}[X]/(\mu).$
Consider the decomposition of $\mu$ into irreducible factors $\mu=(X-a_1)^{m_1}\cdots (X-a_d)^{m_d}P_1^{k_1}\cdots P_r^{k_r},$
where the $P_i's$ are pairwise distinct irreducible polynomials of degree $2$, and the $a_j$'s are pairwise distinct too.
Once may deduce that the maximal ideals with quotient field $\mathbb{R}$ are the ideals $(X-a_i), i=1...r$.
Thus, in general, your ideal  $\mathcal{I}$ is $((X-a_1)\cdots (X-a_d))$.
It is zero if and only if $d=0$, meaning that $\mu$ has no real roots.
Hence $\mathcal{F}_G$ is geometric if and only if the minimal polynomial of $G$ has no real roots.
